# In RStudio, can I test, build and install my current package quickly?

Tags: r, rstudio

When working on a package in `RStudio`, is there a quick way to test, build and install the package?

I currently run:

```
devtools::test()
```

then

```
install.packages(devtools::build(), repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

... but this seems needlessly manual.

Comment: `devtools` has functions `test()`, `build()` and `install()`. You can use `install()` without `build`ing first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RStudio offers a simple way to do this using the GUI. The first step is to create a RStudio project for your package by clicking on *Project: (none)* in the top right corner of RStudio and then choosing new project. I assume you have all your package files in some folder, so you can pick *Existing Directory* in the dialog box and then select your directory.

RStudio will create the project and since it is a package project, the top right panel (which usually contains the *Environment* and *History* tabs) will also contain a *Build* tab:

[image]

This tab offers functionality to build and check your package. You can also easily create a source or binary package. If you use `roxygen2` for documentation, you can configure the project to create the documentation, whenever the package is built (click on *Configure Build Tools...*).

One useful feature is that when you click *Build & Reload*, the package is automatically installed in your R library.